# Android: clear the listview data on button click

Tags: android

In my app I have a listview where it is loading data based on the search keyword, now I want to clear the loaded data on button click.

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        SearchUtils searchUtils = null;
        List<Place> searchResult = null;
        String searchType = null;

        Log.d(TAG, "onPreExecute  start=");
        // show your dialog
        super.onPreExecute();
        Log.d(TAG, "LoadMenuSearch isOldDataToLoad : " + isOldDataToLoad);

        if(!this.isOldDataToLoad){
            this.dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            this.dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);

            this.dialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0) {

                }
            });

            Button morerecords = (Button) activity.findViewById(R.id.morerecords);
            morerecords.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            morerecords.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Do Nothing........................");

                }
            });
            //morerecords.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            final Button closesearch = (Button) activity.findViewById(R.id.closesearch);
            closesearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            closesearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ListView menuSearchListView = (ListView) activity
                            .findViewById(R.id.menusearchlist);
                    searchAdapter.clear();
                    searchAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    closesearch.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }
            });
```

Here in the preexecute I have a button, now when I click the button loaded data should be clear and the listview should get refreshed.

my search adaptor

```
    public SearchAdapter(Activity activity, int viewResourceId, int renderer,
            double latitute, double longitute, String menuId,
            ArrayList<Neighborhood> nhdDetails,
            ArrayList<AttractionData> items, boolean isAddressBook,
            boolean isRecommended) {
        super(activity, viewResourceId, items);
        streetView = new StreetViewUtils(activity);
        streetView.loadHtml();

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) (getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE));
            view = inflater.inflate(renderer, null);
        }

        attractionData = items.get(position);

        Log.d(TAG, "attractionData " + attractionData + " for position "
                + position);
        TextView textName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textName);


        TextView textAddress = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textAddress);
        TextView textPhone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textPhone);
        addFavorite = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.pinsave);

        LinearLayout itemlayer = (LinearLayout) view
                .findViewById(R.id.itemlayer);
        itemlayer.setTag(attractionData);
        textName.setText(attractionData.getfName());

        if (!isRecommended) {
            TextView mapidDisplay = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapid);
            mapidDisplay.setTextSize(Constants.defaultFontSize + 2);
            if (isAddressBook) {
                mapidDisplay.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                mapidDisplay.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            } else {
                mapidDisplay.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                mapidDisplay.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            }

            mapidDisplay.setTag(attractionData);
            mapidDisplay.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    focusLication(v, event);
                    return true;
                }
            });

            Log.d(TAG,
                    "attractionData.getLatitude() ----->"
                            + attractionData.getLatitude()
                            + " attractionData.getLongitude()---> "
                            + attractionData.getLongitude());

            if (attractionData.getLatitude() != 0
                    && attractionData.getLongitude() != 0) {
                mapidDisplay.setText(" " + abbrMapId + (position + 1) + "  ");
                mapidDisplay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                mapidDisplay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        } else {
            ImageView acceptRecommend = (ImageView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.acceptRecommend);
            ImageView rejectRecommend = (ImageView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.rejectRecommend);
            acceptRecommend.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            rejectRecommend.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            acceptRecommend.setTag(attractionData);
            rejectRecommend.setTag(attractionData);

            acceptRecommend.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        AttractionData data = (AttractionData) ((ImageView) v).getTag();
                        ((CityPreferences) activity.getApplication()).updateRecommended(data);
                        items.remove(position);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });

            rejectRecommend.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        AttractionData data = (AttractionData) ((ImageView) v).getTag();
                        long id = data.getId();
                        ((CityPreferences) activity.getApplication()).deleteSavedAttractions(data);
                        data.setStatus("unselect");
                        items.remove(position);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }

        textAddress.setText(attractionData.getAddress());

                    TextView distance = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.distance);
        ImageView distanceDir = (ImageView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.distancedirection);

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(activity.getResources(),
                R.drawable.navigationdir);
        float newRot = new Float(attractionData.getNavigationAngle());

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(newRot);
        // Log.d(TAG, "Roating the Navigation Image : 01" +
        // Constants.mOrientation[0]);
        if (Constants.mOrientation != null && Constants.mOrientation.length > 0) {
            double bearingToTarget = newRot + Constants.mOrientation[0];
            double drawingAngle = Math.toRadians(bearingToTarget)
                    - (Math.PI / 2);
            float cos = (float) Math.cos(drawingAngle);
            float sin = (float) Math.sin(drawingAngle);

            matrix.setSinCos(sin, cos);
            Bitmap redrawnBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,
                    bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);

            distanceDir.setImageBitmap(redrawnBitmap);

            // distanceDir.setRotation(90);
        } else {
            Bitmap redrawnBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,
                    bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
            distanceDir.setImageBitmap(redrawnBitmap);
        }

        if (attractionData.getDistance() != null
                && !attractionData.getDistance().equals("")) {
            distance.setText(attractionData.getDistance());
        } else {
            distance.setText("");
        }
        if (attractionData.getLatitude() != 0.00
                && attractionData.getLongitude() != 0.00) {
            distanceDir.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            distance.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            distanceDir.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            distance.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        // Log.d(TAG, "end to search distance -->");
        LinearLayout llReviews = (LinearLayout) view
                .findViewById(R.id.reviewsrating);

        llReviews.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        GridView gridview = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.ratingView);
        TextView textRating = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rating);
        TextView textReviews = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.reviews);
        textRating.setText("(" + attractionData.getRating() + ")");
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getContext(), attractionData
                .getRating()));
        // code for review
        if (attractionData.getReview() != null
                && (attractionData.getReview().equals("1") || attractionData
                        .getReview().equals("0"))) {
            textReviews.setText(attractionData.getReview() + " review");
        } else if (attractionData.getReview() != null) {
            textReviews.setText(attractionData.getReview() + " reviews");
        } else {
            textReviews.setText("0 review");
        }

        textReviews.setTag(attractionData.getReviewUrl());
        textReviews.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String webURL = (String) v.getTag();
                utils.openWebURL(v.getContext(), webURL);
            }
        });

        if (Constants.isDefineNeighbourHood) {
            addFavorite.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            if (attractionData.getId() > 0) {
                if (menuId != null && menuId.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.menuFavouritePlaceId)) {
                    addFavorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.favorite_active);
                    addFavorite.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    attractionData.setStatus("select");
                    EditAttraction editAttraction = new EditAttraction(activity, false);
                    itemlayer.setOnLongClickListener(editAttraction);
                    if (!Constants.isEysonly) {
                        Loginmyplaces loginmyplaces = new Loginmyplaces(activity);
                        itemlayer.setOnClickListener(loginmyplaces);
                    }
                } else {
                    addFavorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.favorite_active);
                    addFavorite.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    attractionData.setStatus("select");
                    EditAttraction editAttraction = new EditAttraction(activity, true);
                    itemlayer.setOnLongClickListener(editAttraction);
                }
            } else {
                addFavorite.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                addFavorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.favorite);
                attractionData.setStatus("unselect");
                EditAttraction editAttraction = new EditAttraction(activity,
                        true);
                itemlayer.setOnLongClickListener(editAttraction);

            }
        }
        // Log.d(TAG, "Constants.totalFavorite : status : " +
        // attractionData.getStatus() + " for " + attractionData.getName());
        addFavorite.setTag(attractionData);
        addFavorite.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    AttractionData data = (AttractionData) ((ImageView) v)
                            .getTag();
                    ImageView currentpinsave = (ImageView) v
                            .findViewById(R.id.pinsave);
                    Log.d(TAG,
                            "Constants.totalFavorite : status : "
                                    + data.getStatus());
                    Log.d(TAG, "Constants.totalFavorite : Resource : "
                            + currentpinsave);
                    if (data.getStatus() != null
                            && data.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("select")) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "data.status  " + data.getStatus());
                        currentpinsave.setImageResource(R.drawable.favorite);
                        currentpinsave.setTag(data);
                        long id = data.getId();
                        ((CityPreferences) activity.getApplication())
                                .deleteSavedAttractions(data);
                        data.setStatus("unselect");
                        currentpinsave.setImageResource(R.drawable.favorite);
                        new DeleteFromConstance().execute(id);
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "data.status  " + data.getStatus());
                        currentpinsave
                                .setImageResource(R.drawable.favorite_active);
                        currentpinsave.setTag(data);
                        data.setMenuId(menuId);
                        streetView.checkPhotoView(data);
                        ((CityPreferences) activity.getApplication())
                                .saveMyAttractions(data, true);
                        data.setStatus("select");
                        utils.checkFavoriteCity(activity, data);
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    break;
                }
                return true;
            }

        });

        if (!isRecommended) {

            if (attractionData.getImages() != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "ImageUtils --> inside blob saved");
                ImageView placeImage = (ImageView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.placeimage);
                placeImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                placeImage.setImageBitmap(attractionData.getImages());

            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "ImageUtils --> inside blob not saved");
                ImageView placeImage = (ImageView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.placeimage);
                placeImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        }

        ImageView navigationImage = (ImageView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.navigationImage);
        ImageView streetViewImage = (ImageView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.streetview);

        if (attractionData.getLatitude() != 0
                && attractionData.getLongitude() != 0) {
            navigationImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.navigation);
            navigationImage.setTag(attractionData);

            navigationImage.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        if (utils.isConnectionAvailable(v.getContext())) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Navigator.class);
                            AttractionData data = (AttractionData) ((ImageView) v).getTag();
                            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                            // add data to bundle
                            bundle.putString("startlatitude", latitute + "");
                            bundle.putString("startlongitude", longitute + "");
                            bundle.putString("latitude", data.getLatitude() + "");
                            bundle.putString("longitude", data.getLongitude() + "");
                            intent.putExtras(bundle);
                            v.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(intent).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK));
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), v.getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.noconnection), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        break;
                    }

                    return true;
                }
            });


            streetViewImage.setTag(attractionData);
            streetViewImage.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        AttractionData data = (AttractionData) v.getTag();
                        Location location = new Location("");
                        location.setLatitude(data.getLatitude());
                        location.setLongitude(data.getLongitude());
                        streetView.checkStreetView(location);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        break;
                }
                    return true;
                }});

            streetViewImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            navigationImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            streetViewImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            navigationImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        LinearLayout commentLayout = (LinearLayout) view
                .findViewById(R.id.commentLayout);
        if (attractionData.getComments() != null
                && !attractionData.getComments().trim().equals("")) {
            commentLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            TextView comment = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.comment);
            comment.setText(attractionData.getComments());
        } else {
            commentLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        ImageView phImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.phoneImage);

        String phoneNo = attractionData.getPhoneNo();
        if (attractionData.getMobileNo() != null
                && !attractionData.getMobileNo().equals("")
                && !attractionData.getMobileNo().equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
            if (phoneNo != null && !phoneNo.equals("")
                    && !phoneNo.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
                phoneNo = phoneNo + ",\n" + attractionData.getMobileNo();
            } else {
                phoneNo = attractionData.getMobileNo();
            }

        }

        Log.d(TAG, "------------------> phoneNo " + phoneNo);

        if (phoneNo != null && !phoneNo.equals("") && !phoneNo.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
            textPhone.setText(phoneNo);
            textPhone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            phImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            phImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.phone);
            phImage.setTag(phoneNo);
            phImage.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    String phone = (String) ((ImageView) v).getTag();
                    Log.d(TAG, "onTouch phone--" + phone);
                    utils.dailPhone(v.getContext(), phone); 
                    break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        break;
                    }


                    return true;

                    }
            });

        } else {
            phImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            textPhone.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }

        LinearLayout htmllayout = (LinearLayout) view
                .findViewById(R.id.htmllayout);

        if (attractionData.getHtmlAttributions() != null
                && !attractionData.getHtmlAttributions().equals("")
                && !attractionData.getHtmlAttributions().equalsIgnoreCase(
                        "null")) {
            htmllayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            TextView htmlAttributions = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.htmlAttributions);
            TextView htmlAttributionsLink = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.htmlAttributionsLink);
            htmlAttributions.setText(attractionData.getHtmlAttributions());
            htmlAttributionsLink.setText(attractionData
                    .getHtmlAttributionsLink());
            htmlAttributionsLink.setTag(attractionData);
            htmlAttributionsLink.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    AttractionData data = (AttractionData) ((TextView) v)
                            .getTag();
                    utils.openWebURL(v.getContext(),
                            data.getHtmlAttributionsUrl());
                    new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    return true;

                }
            });

        } else {
            htmllayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        // ********************************************* changing for showing
        // the zagat review and price level
        String priceTag = attractionData.getPriceTag();
        String zagatReview = attractionData.getZagatReview();
        Log.d(TAG, "Extra Parameter Setup : " + attractionData.getfName()
                + " URL : " + attractionData.getReviewUrl());
        Log.d(TAG, "Extra Parameter Setup : priceTag : " + priceTag
                + " zagatReview : " + zagatReview);
        if (priceTag != null && !priceTag.equals("")) {
            ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pricelevelvalue))
                    .setText(priceTag);
        } else {
            view.findViewById(R.id.pricelevelvalue).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        if (zagatReview != null && !zagatReview.equals("")) {
            view.findViewById(R.id.moredetail_review).setVisibility(
                    View.VISIBLE);
            ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.zagatreviewvalue))
                    .setText(zagatReview);
        } else {
            view.findViewById(R.id.moredetail_review).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        Reservation reservation = attractionData.getReservation();
        List<PlaceMenu> menus = attractionData.getMenu();

        if ((reservation != null) || (menus != null && !menus.isEmpty())) {
            view.findViewById(R.id.moredetail_menu_reservation).setVisibility(
                    View.VISIBLE);
            TextView reservationTextView = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.reservationvalues);
            if (reservation != null && reservation.getName() != null
                    && !reservation.getName().equals("")) {
                Log.d(TAG,
                        "Extra Parameter Setup : reservation "
                                + reservation.getName() + " URL : "
                                + reservation.getUrl());
                view.findViewById(R.id.reservation).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                reservationTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                reservationTextView.setText(reservation.getName());
                reservationTextView.setTag(reservation.getUrl());
                reservationTextView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        utils.openWebURL(v.getContext(),
                                (String) ((TextView) v).getTag());
                        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        return true;

                    }
                });
            } else {
                view.findViewById(R.id.reservation).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                reservationTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            TextView placemenuTextView = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.placemenu);
            if (menus != null && !menus.isEmpty()) {
                Log.d(TAG,
                        "Extra Parameter Setup : Menu Size : " + menus.size());

                placemenuTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                placemenuTextView.setTag(menus);
                placemenuTextView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            List<PlaceMenu> placeMenu = (List<PlaceMenu>) ((TextView) v).getTag();
                            ArrayList<DialogData> data = new ArrayList<DialogData>();
                            for (int i = 0; i < placeMenu.size(); i++) {
                                DialogData dialogData = new DialogData();
                                dialogData.setName(placeMenu.get(i).getName());
                                dialogData.setValue(placeMenu.get(i).getUrl());
                                dialogData.setType("url");
                                data.add(dialogData);
                            }
                            utils.showPopupDailog(v.getContext(), data, "Menu");
                            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            break;
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                });
            } else {
                placemenuTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        } else {
            view.findViewById(R.id.moredetail_menu_reservation).setVisibility(
                    View.GONE);
        }

        if (attractionData.getHotelReview() != null) {
            PlaceHotelReview hotelReview = null;
            TextView textView = null;
            textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.hotelreviewtext);
            if (menuId != null && menuId.equals(Constants.menuHotelId)) {
                textView.setText(R.string.hotelPricing);
            } else {
                textView.setText(R.string.hotelreview);
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "Hotel Review Step 02 : ");
            LinearLayout rl = (LinearLayout) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.hotelreview);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            view.findViewById(R.id.hotelreview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            rl.removeAllViews();

            rl.addView(textView, lp);
            for (int i = 0; i < attractionData.getHotelReview().size(); i++) {
                hotelReview = attractionData.getHotelReview().get(i);
                Log.d(TAG, "Hotel Review Step 03 : " + hotelReview);
                textView = new TextView(activity);
                Log.d(TAG, "Hotel Review Step 04 : " + hotelReview.getName());
                Log.d(TAG, "Hotel Review Step 05 : " + hotelReview.getReviews());
                textView.setText(hotelReview.getName().replaceAll("\"", ""));
                if (i == attractionData.getHotelReview().size() - 1) {
                    textView.setPadding(5, 5, 0, 5);
                } else if (i == attractionData.getHotelReview().size() - 1) {
                    textView.setPadding(5, 0, 0, 5);
                } else {
                    textView.setPadding(5, 5, 0, 0);
                }
                textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0000ff"));
                textView.setTag(hotelReview);
                Log.d(TAG, "Hotel Review Step 05 : ");
                textView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            PlaceHotelReview hotelReview = (PlaceHotelReview) v.getTag();
                            utils.openWebURL(v.getContext(), hotelReview.getUrl().replaceAll("\"", ""));
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            break;
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                });
                rl.addView(textView, lp);
            }
        } else {
            view.findViewById(R.id.hotelreview).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        TextView openCloseTime = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.openclosedesc);
        if (attractionData.getOpenCloseDesc() != null
                && !attractionData.getOpenCloseDesc().equals("")
                && !attractionData.getOpenCloseDesc().equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
            openCloseTime.setText(attractionData.getOpenCloseDesc());
        } else {
            openCloseTime.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }


        itemlayer.setOnTouchListener(new DetectMotion(activity, isAddressBook));

        if (position % 2 == 0)
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listshape);
        else
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.favoritebody);

        return view;
    }

    private void focusLication(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            AttractionData ad = (AttractionData) v.getTag();
            Constants.isMaptobeLoaded = true;
            if (ad.getLatitude() != 0 && ad.getLongitude() != 0) {
                if (Constants.isDefineNeighbourHood) {
                    if (Constants.focusLocationNH == null) {
                        Constants.focusLocationNH = new Location("");
                    }
                    Constants.focusLocationNH.setLatitude(ad.getLatitude());
                    Constants.focusLocationNH.setLongitude(ad.getLongitude());

                    if (Constants.myNeighborHoodLocation == null) {
                        Constants.myNeighborHoodLocation = new Location("");
                    }
                    Constants.myNeighborHoodLocation.setLatitude(ad
                            .getLatitude());
                    Constants.myNeighborHoodLocation.setLongitude(ad
                            .getLongitude());

                } else {

                    if (Constants.focusLocation == null) {
                        Constants.focusLocation = new Location("");
                    }
                    Constants.focusLocation.setLatitude(ad.getLatitude());
                    Constants.focusLocation.setLongitude(ad.getLongitude());
                }
                activity.finish();
                if (isAddressBook) {
                    Constants.isPABImportant = true;
                    activity.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left,
                            R.anim.slide_out_left);
                } else {
                    Constants.isPABImportant = false;
                    activity.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_out_right,
                            R.anim.slide_in_right);
                }
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break;
        }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just notify the  listview after clearing the data of adapter i guess searchAdapter is your adapter . SearchAdapter is a custom adapter where you need to clear data based on type of adapter then call notifyDataSetChanged.

Comment: my searhadapter is array adapter i just need to call notifydatasetchange on button click?

Comment: getting error on clear, using this menuSearchListView.clear();

Comment: developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/… use clear method on adapter object and then notify – android2013 3 mins ago edit

Comment: Show your SearchAdapter code  , are you calling super. in constructor? have you overridden any clear methods ?

Comment: i did this searchAdapter.clear(); searchAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); its clearing but again loading after clearing , i want the data to be cleared and after performing search only other data should load

Comment: i cannot access the code please put it here . what you mean by loading again? just after you see clearing ?

Comment: edited my question with search adapter please look ...loading again means it is getting cleared and in one second it is loading again.

Comment: getview seems ok , from where your searchResults coming ? in async task? for testing wait for sometime after you do press search say 10 seconds and then clear , is the results still loaded again?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this way

```
    list.clear();
    adpater.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

/// remove item from list.

```
adapter.clear();
adpater.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Not all Adapters have a clear() method. ArrayAdapter does, but ListAdapter or SimpleAdapter doesn't

Comment: @OnurOzbek Not all Adapters have a clear() method. ArrayAdapter does, but ListAdapter or SimpleAdapter doesn't

Answer (score 0):

This is the code for clearing listview data on button click

```
Button yourbutton; // init it
yourButon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
       yourList.clear(); // this list which you hava passed in Adapter for your listview
       yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // notify to listview for refresh
});
```

Comment: in place of this  yourList.clear(); i placed menuSearchListView.clear();

Comment: I don't know man hows you actually implemented here just code is not enough where actually you have problem sorry

Comment: problem is i just need to clear the loaded search results ..i have one  search adapter and one loadmenusearh asynctask class and a menuutils class

Comment: ok then use clear() method of your list/arraylist or if you store your data in array then re-init it and then just class notifyDataSetChanged() of your adapter that's it

Comment: clearing the listview like this menuSearchListView.clear(); is not working..instead i tried to clear my adapter and the notfiydatasetchange..but it is giving somemore results